# How do I remove the blue border when I click on a hotspot mapped to my image in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have created a hotspots on an image and when ever I click on an area of the image now a blue box appreas (in all browsers). I have tried everything including adding:

```
#mapimage {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;border:0
}


#mapimage area {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;border:0
} 

#imagemap area {
outline:none;
}

a img { border: none; }
```

Here is the code:

```
<img id="mapimage" src="http://intra.ontariocourts.on.ca/ocj/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/regionsofthecourt.jpg" alt="regionsofthecourt" usemap="#regions" width="480" height="468" /></div>
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: do you have a link to it?

Comment: instead of border:0, try border:0px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `outline:none;` to `a img` as well.

Answer (score 0):

add hidefocus=true to your < img > tag

```
<img id=......................... hidefocus=true/>
```

and also in your css

```
img #imagemap, map area { outline:none;}
```

it should be working. give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through dozens of forums, this worked for me. Add the code below to your CSS:

```css
a img { 
  border: none; 
}

area {
  outline: none;
}
```